# How to emulate an XMM register behavior in Python

Tags: python

How can I achieve the same behavior which I have with an 128 bit assembly register for unsigned integers.

For example when you shift right, most significant bits will be zeroed, or when you shift left, the total size will not expand and will continue to stay 128bits.
Numpy goes only up until 64bit integers.

Here's a practical example:

```
int128bits = 0x00000001000000010000000100000001
int128bits = int128bits << 0xff
```

Expectation:

int128bits = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000

Reality:

int128bits = 0x8000000080000000800000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Try `(int128bits << 0xff) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` to mask off the bits that shifted outside of the low 128 bits.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found by accident with PeachPy

```
from peachpy import *
from peachpy.x86_64 import *

def decrypt(dword1):
        #Assembler instructions to Transform
        x = Argument(uint64_t)
        with Function("DotProduct", (x,), uint64_t) as asm_function:
            #Load var and Shift right
            LOAD.ARGUMENT(rax, x)
            MOVQ(xmm2, rax)
            MOVLHPS(xmm2, xmm2)
            PSRLDQ(xmm2, 0xf)
            
            MOVQ(rax, xmm1)
            RETURN(rax)

        #Read Assembler Return
        python_function = asm_function.finalize(abi.detect()).encode().load()
        return python_function(dword1)
        
print(decrypt(0x0000000100000001))
```